# How to count the number of data more than 0 in each hour column and make it a total row?

Tags: mysql

Here's the image of the final wanted result:

[image]

And here's the used MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    unit,
    dt,
    pengguna,
    loader,
    material,
    kubik,
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=6,1,NULL)) AS '6am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=7,1,NULL)) AS '7am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=8,1,NULL)) AS '8am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=9,1,NULL)) AS '9am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=10,1,NULL)) AS '10am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=11,1,NULL)) AS '11am',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=12,1,NULL)) AS '12pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=13,1,NULL)) AS '1pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=14,1,NULL)) AS '2pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=15,1,NULL)) AS '3pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=16,1,NULL)) AS '4pm',
    COUNT(IF(HOUR(tgl)=17,1,NULL)) AS '5pm',
    COUNT(dt) AS truckcount,
    SUM(kubik) AS totkubik,
    SUM(distance) AS totjarak 
FROM 
    ritase 
WHERE 
    unit LIKE 'EX 815' 
    AND tgl BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 06:00:00') 
    AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 17:59:59') 
    AND material IN ('SOIL','CLAY','MUD','LIQUID MUD','SAND','BLEND','PARTING') 
GROUP BY dt, material 
ORDER BY pengguna ASC
```

How to count the number of data that are more than 0 in each hour column and make it a total row?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977), [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)